# Settings position properties

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile

Is view properties methods like `setLeft()` or `setTop()` is only changes property of the view, but not actually moving view into another location? I assuming that view should change it's location. Documentation doesn't covers that well.

Comment: Yeh you are right, it will move the view and change the location as well.

Answer (score 0):

It should change the location of the view as well as the properties.  You can also do it by simply defining the property, like this: `view.left = 5;`